# psexec fails against windows 10 remote target

Tags: shell, windows-10, remote-access, psexec, sysinternals

Does psexec work against Windows 10 remote hosts? I'm running psexec from a Windows 7 machine. When the remote host is Windows 8.1, it works, when the remote host is Windows 10, it fails as below:

C:\Windows 7>psexec -h -u Admin -p passwordHere -n 280 \xxx.xx.xxx.xxx ipconfig

PsExec v2.11 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2014 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Could not start PSEXESVC service on xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:
The remote procedure call failed and did not execute.

Any clues appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Found this on a Microsoft forum, worked for me.

Open regedit from start. Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System`

Add REG_DWORD (32 bit) `LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy` and set value to `1`.

Answer (score -2):

You must run psexec on the remote machine and accept the end-user agreement (EUA) before running psexec remotely.
This can also be done by adding '-accepteula' switch to your command or by editing the remote machine's registry (less recommended).

Comment: Thanks for the info, but unfortunately, it didn't help. I tried both suggestions, same error. I worked around this by writing my own remote shell, so the issue is a little less urgent, but would prefer to use psexec if I can get past this error.

Comment: Another thing that you may want to make sure is that 'File and printer sharing' is turned on on the remote machine, which is mandatory for psexec to be executed remotely:
1. Right click on the network icon in the System Tray.
2. Open Network and Sharing Center
3. Change advanced sharing settings
4. Turn on file and printer sharing